# correct geometry?

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

I want to create a container for my pen nibs in blender to later 3D print. I was wondering if there are improvements I can make to the model?
I have my doubts about the edge loops near the outside border? (selected in the attached image)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about 3D printing but for graphics & especially animation its important to keep a clean mesh. It's good practice anyhow and will make your life simpler. Also make sure that at the end your Object is centered, all your origins are at an appropriate place and the scale of your object is 1 (instead of 0.00023 in your case) and rotation is reset. Paying attention to these small things will prevent you from going to hell.

I fixed it for you: [image]

Optimal work progress, for next time: https://youtu.be/aO1UWJjKaFk

Keybinds used:

- Shift+A: Add new Cube
- Ctrl+R: Loop Cut
- Shift+Tab: Snap transform (The red magnet at the bottom toolbar)
- G: Move stuff
- E: Extrude stuff
- G + X/Y/Z + number: Move stuff along an axis by a certain distance
- E + X/Y/Z + number: Extrude stuff along an axis by a certain distance
- Ctrl+A: Reset Location/Rotation/Scale

[image]

Comment: wow, thanks alot! The previous container I made was more along the lines of what you did minus some of the loopcuts. Thanks for the video demonstration. That helps for when I'll want to model something similar in the future!